# How to return from execution stack immediately as value is found

Tags: laravel

I have search functionality. If a user wants to find anothers' threads, it comes in as a boolean TRUE.

I am able to dd($threads) in its execution stack, but it seems like it follows through with the rest of the execution stack.

For example:

```
    public function scopeSearch(Builder $query, ?string $search = null, ?array $users = null, ?bool $title = null, ?bool $threads = null)
    {

        if ($threads == TRUE) {
            return $query->whereHas('thread', function ($query) use ($users) { return $query->whereIn('threads.user_id', $users)->toSql(); });
        }
        
        elseif (!$search) {
            return $query->when($users, function ($q) use ($users) { $q->whereIn('user_id', $users)
                ->whereHas('thread', function ($query) use ($users) { $query->whereIn('threads.user_id', $users); })
                ->orWhereHas('reply', function ($query) use ($users) { $query->whereIn('replies.user_id', $users); })
                ->orWhereHas('product', function ($query) use ($users) { $query->whereIn('products.user_id', $users); })
                ->orWhereHas('review', function ($query) use ($users) { $query->whereIn('reviews.user_id', $users); })
                ;
            });
        }

}
```

I can dd($threads), but want to know how I can *stop it right there*, as it's not returning the toSql statement, and, I want it to just return the threads.

Any help is appreciated :) thanks all :).

Answer (score 0):

In my controller method:

I had:

```
if ($threads) {
}

if (!empty($variable) {
}
```

It should have been "paired together" like such

```
if ($threads) {
} elseif (!empty($variable)) {
} elseif (etc, etc) {
}
```